# Collection to combobox

Tags: excel, vba, collections, combobox

I created a collection (CollWk) in a macro. This collection contains the weeknumbers that exist in a particular sheet.
I would like to put this collection in a combobox (or drop down list) so that the user can select a weeknumber.

This is what i have so far

```
Dim CollWk As New Collection

For i = wkLow To wkHigh
    CollWk.Add i
Next
```

this is were i create the collection. Currnetly the sheet "ExtraData"is active
The combobox is on the sheet "StartSheet"

I've tried to do combobox1.additem i in the for loop to just add items but it doens't work

when i try to add something to the combobox as

Startsheet.ComboBox1.Additem "Hello"

it won't run

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through the collection and add each item in the ComboBox like this :

```
Sub Test_Henk_Schins()

Dim CollWk As Collection
Dim aWeek

'With UserForm1.ComboBox1
With Sheets("SheetName").ComboBox1
    .Clear
    For Each aWeek In CollWk
        .AddItem aWeek
    Next aWeek
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get error 424, Object requierd. Do i have assign aWeek as something?

Comment: On which line? you can declare `aWeek` of the same type that the objects that are in your collection (I don't know that is why I didn't precise). Have you changed `UserForm1` and `ComboBox1` to fit your UserForm's and ComboBox's names?

Comment: More importantly, is the combobox in a userform or in excel? If in excel, what did you use to create it (which menu so that we can know if it is an ActiveX, a Control, ...)

Comment: it is in excel (and I did create it as an ActiveX)

Comment: Ok so try the edit and change `SheetName` and `ComboBox1` to fit the name of your sheet and combobox

Comment: Thanks R3uK. Got it. Thanks all for your quick responses and sorry for my english. Have to translate parts of my code from dutch to english and back.

Comment: @HenkSchins : No problem, glad I could help! Take a minute to take the tour and see how to accept answer and vote on post to make SO a better place! Enjoy